# Does Skype use only Ipv4 or also IPv6?

Tags: skype, ipv6, voip

A simple question. Does Skype use IP version 6? If yes, how can i set it to use this type of addresses?

When IPv4 is not available, Skype seems to have problems:

[image]

Are there other VOIP application using IP version 6 (like VIBER or Whatsapp)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve specifically?  Why does it matter if Skype uses IPv4 or IPv6 to connect to its servers?

Comment: Ping two hosts using their IPv6 during a skype call. It's just for curiosity

Comment: Skype is no longer P2P.  I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

The Skype for Linux beta was released this week, and it now works in an IPv6-only environment. It's worked on Android over IPv6-only for some time now.

I haven't tried Apple or Windows platforms (I don't run them).

Answer (score 0):

Skype does not yet support IPv6, although several people are repeatingly requesting it at Skype's Community Forums.

Skype for Business, however, does indeed [support IPv6.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204624.aspx)

Comment: You should quote all relevant information from any links you provide.  While I could edit your answer myself, I am not going to do that, because it won't prevent you not quoting relevant information in the future

Comment: @Ramhound was right. Now your first link is dead.